# siunitx always writes x10^0

Tags: siunitx

I am using the `siunitx` package to write `\num{15}` or `\SI{0.98}{\bar}`.
The output is always with a power notation, like:

[image]

[image]

How can I avoid this notation?

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example such that we know which settings  your're using. Additionally exactly which version of `siunitx` are you using? There are many updates tight now, so have you updated lately to see if that fixes the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage[retain-zero-exponent=false]{siunitx}
```

Just solved it, the argument `retain-zero-exponent` was accidently set to `true`

Comment: The default is `retain-zero-exponent = false`, so you could just skip setting it entirely